# Wired ethernet on Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 only works if it's powered; how do I know if an ethernet to USB-C adapter is powered?

Tags: xiaomi, ethernet

My relative has a Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 from 2022. We use wired ethernet and the only ethernet to USB-C adapter that works for that phone (unlike my Samsung Galaxy) is the fact that the ethernet adapter has to be powered. Mine uses a passive ethernet to USB-C connection.

I was wondering if any of y'all know how do I know if the ethernet to USB-C adapters that have a light turned on near the RJ54 connection is also powered, or are the ones who only say that they have charging capabilities the ones that will work?

For example:

- Here's the one that works for him: [Belkin USB C To Ethernet + Charge Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086SV2FK4)
- And here's the one that has the light: [WALNEW USB Type C to RJ45 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter Cable Converter](https://www.amazon.ca/Ethernet-Adapter-WALNEW-Converter-Thunderbolt/dp/B0B8RFB9KD)
- And this is the one similar to the one I use, which doesn't have anything flashy to it: [TP-Link USB C To Ethernet Adapter(UE300C)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HQBC678)

We don't want to spend $30 on another one (the cable for his is starting to get destroyed with wear and tear), so I'm trying to find another solution for the RJ45 connection to his phone.

Thanks!

Comment: I would assume that it is a driver problem. You need an adapter with an ethernet chip your device's kernel has built-in drivers. So before buying an adapter you should find out which chip is used and the  how good Linux support is. If the reviews on Linux mention a driver/kernel module which had to be installed then this adapter is not suitable for your device.